# What does binding a Rails Server to 0.0.0.0 buy you?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, bind, server

I am using "www.xip.io" as a DNS wildcard for testing on different devices. I set my primary domain to my IP address. I fire up a rails server with `bundle exec rails server` and I go here `www.<ip_address>.xip.io:3000` and notice my rails server doesn't respond.

However, if I bind my rails server to 0.0.0.0 like so `bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0`, it works! I don't understand what 0.0.0.0 is telling my server for this to work. Can someone make sense of this?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Binding to `0.0.0.0` tells the service to bind to **all IP addresses** on your machine. Rails server used to do this by default, but with 4.2 changed to binding only to `localhost`.

Basically if it's only bound to `localhost` then it will only respond locally to either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` which can't work through a DNS service because it's not a public IP address.

When you use `0.0.0.0` it will bind to localhost **and** to your routable IP address.

Comment: You're welcome, it was a nasty (poorly publicized) gotcha for a lot of people.

Comment: Oh man, this had me going absolutely crazy. If you're trying to run rails from a docker container and you don't specify this option, the docker container does not respond, no matter what you do. This is a lifesaver.

Comment: Isnt' binding to only localhost better ? Especially if you are behind a proxy and want your site example.com to forward to  localhost:3000 internally ?

Comment: I mean yes, if you have a reverse proxy that means Rails only needs to know about localhost, then you'd just run `rails s` without any binding (which binds to localhost). That's not what OP had.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use binding any time you're in a guest/virtual machine.

Comment: It's true that binding to a non-localhost address is important in that context... it would be useful to say a lot more than this if you're wanting this answer to stand on its own, though.  (And indeed, it's binding either way, it's just a question of whether it's binding to the wildcard (0.0.0.0) or localhost or what.)  Downvoting for both lack of precision and lack of a full answer to the original question, though I'd be happy to re-visit given an update to the answer, because I definitely do think there's something useful in this.