# Docker Rails Server Refusing Connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, docker, docker-machine

I have Rail-Api Server that I setup with my Dockerfile and I'm trying to access it from the host but I a getting Connection refused after starting the rails server and curling the Docker container.

#### curl

```
curl 192.168.99.100:32776
```

#### Docker Container : Ports

[image]

#### iptables -L on 'docker-machine ssh default'

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:5000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:3000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:ssh
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:6.6

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install git openssl-devel openssh-server sudo openssl readline-devel readline zlib-devel zlib libxml2-devel libxml2 libxslt-devel libxslt nginx tar gcc libaio libaio-devel -y
RUN rpm -Uvh https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/el/6/x86_64/chef-12.5.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
RUN sed -i -e "s/Defaults    requiretty.*/ #Defaults    requiretty/g" /etc/sudoers

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

RUN useradd -m -u 1000 -G wheel deploy && echo '%wheel  ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/wheel
USER deploy
RUN mkdir ~/dev

RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv/
RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

ENV PATH ~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN source ~/.bash_profile
ENV CONFIGURE_OPTS --disable-install-doc

RUN rbenv install 2.2.3
RUN rbenv global 2.2.3
RUN bash -l -c 'gem update --system'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem update'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem install bundler rails-api --no-rdoc --no-ri'

COPY oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
COPY oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
COPY oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm

RUN sudo rpm -Uvh /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
RUN sudo rpm -Uvh /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
RUN sudo rpm -Uvh /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm

RUN sudo touch /etc/sysconfig/network

RUN NLS_LANG=American_America.UTF8
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib

EXPOSE 22
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 5000
```

Comment: how are you starting your container? Also, how are you configuring your `entry` ports from your host?

Comment: I've tried using the command line ` docker run -it -p ....` as well as just using kitematic to configure and run the container. @Rico

Comment: you running curl from your Mac?

Comment: @Rico Yes, I've tried it when inside the vm as well

Comment: what's you full docker command you are using to start the app? or what command you are using to start the rails server?  Also, can you ssh to the container?

Comment: @Rico `docker run -it -p 49170:22 -p 49171:3000 -p 49172:5000 d6bca05bf7d2 bash `

Comment: and what about your rails command ? with full output

Comment: want to see what you are binding to...

Comment: @Rico I just run rail server binding to default port 3000

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna take a wild guess, I think you are using Rails 4.2.x or later (which is the latest as of Today) and its binding to `127.0.0.1` or/and `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0`. Check this too : [What does binding a Rails Server to 0.0.0.0 buy you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083885/what-does-binding-a-rails-server-to-0-0-0-0-buy-you0)

Try running:

```
bundle exec rails server -b0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I"m still not getting a response. In your answer you meant `server` not `console` ?

Comment: so do you have any iptables ? inside your container by any chance ?