# Ruby on Rails. How to run two servers (different apps) on Amazon Ec2 at same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5

I am triyn to deploy two different rails app in one Ec2 i can run one each time and work ok, but i need the 2 app running at same time and that can be accessed from anywhere not only localhost,I enable (add rule) two tcp port 3000 and 3001, this is my try:

```
/path/app1$ rails s -d 

/path/app2$ rails s -b0.0.0.0 -p 3001 -d
```

this is the ps -ef command output

```
dev+  3028     1  0 17:10 ?        00:00:00 puma 3.11.2 (tcp://localhost:3000) [/]
dev+  3160     1  0 17:14 ?        00:00:00 puma 3.11.3 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3001) [/]
```

also try to run app1 with -b0.0.0.0 so it can listen from anywhere, but same result: only 1 app is listening on 0.0.0.0.
What I am missing? How can I run two servers at same time and listen both on 0.0.0.0.
thanks

Comment: create 2 virtual hosts with different conf files and then in the name servers point them both to this instance

Comment: @DhavalChheda can you give me an example or be more clearer please?

Comment: https://geekflare.com/multiple-domains-on-one-server-with-apache-nginx/

Answer (score 1):

By default, according to the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html), the server will only listen on the localhost / loopback interface. This is actually confirmed in the output snippet that you posted.

In the first command for `app1`, you aren't telling it to listen on `0.0.0.0`, so you'd need to change your first command to:

```
/path/app1$ rails s -b0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -d
```

Both applications can listen on `0.0.0.0`, but they can't share the same port. You have already configured `app1` to listen on port 3000 (Rails default), and `app2` to listen on port 3001, so they should both coexist peacefully, once you make the change above.

See also: [What does binding a Rails Server to 0.0.0.0 buy you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083885/what-does-binding-a-rails-server-to-0-0-0-0-buy-you)