# Rails 5 development server - access from the outside

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an android phone and I need to send some requests to a rails server.

I do the usual stuff by picking up the ip address from `ifconfig` then using that ip address on port 3000.

It does not work. Even if I run something like `wget ip_address:3000` it does not.

Is it because the port 3000 is blocked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rails server only binds to localhost, you need to use the `-b` option, eg. `rails s -b 0`  This will bind to 0.0.0.0 (ie. all addresses).  My answer here goes into more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29084070/152786

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I hope this becomes more visible, as I spent ages looking for something that should be so easy to find