# Config URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

My IP address is 10.0.5.140. In my computer, I can run my Rails source with URL:`localhost:8888`. But I want to run my source in other computers, so I must change `localhost:8888` to `10.0.5.140:8888`. How can I config that?

Answer (score 0):

You can run starting server with binding option `rails s --binding 0.0.0.0`

Refer 
[What does binding a Rails Server to 0.0.0.0 buy you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083885/what-does-binding-a-rails-server-to-0-0-0-0-buy-you/29084070)

Comment: I know this way bro, but I want to config in my source :) Anyway, I found the solution. You can config in `config/puma.rb` with this line `set_default_host '10.0.5.140'`